# How can I do add an item to the repository at the end of the list in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-edittext, items

I have several EditText fields: Title, Description, Date. Also, there is a Save button. By clicking on it, the fields should be validated that they are not empty, and if everything is correct, then a toast will appear that the item has been added, the add screen (NewItemActivity) will close, and the new item should be added to the repository at the end of the list. I made checks for empty fields. Tell me how to add an item to the repository at the end of the list with a calling toast and closing the screen? I assumed that the ViewModel needs to be done, but I'm not sure. If you can give an example with a detailed description, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To close any `Activity`, call its `finish()` method. For instance if you want to close the `NewItemActivity` by clicking on `saveButton`,

```kotlin
saveButton.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Closing newActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    updateMechanism() // whatever you want to do...
    finish()
}
```

And to add an item at the end of the list:

replace the `List`

```kotlin
interface MyItemsRepository {
    val items: List<ItemModel>
```

with `ArrayList`

```kotlin
interface MyItemsRepository {
    val items: ArrayList<ItemModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very straightforward, just create a new method inside your interface:

```
interface MyItemsRepository {

    val items: ArrayList<ItemModel>    // change to this from List<ItemModel>

    ....

    fun saveNewItem(item: ItemModel)

}
```

Then implement the same in your repository implementation:

```
class MyItemsRepositoryImpl private constructor() : MyItemsRepository {

    ....

    override fun saveNewItem(item: ItemModel) {
        items.add(item)
    }

}
```

Call this method from ViewModel:

```
class ContentViewModel(
    private val repository: MyItemsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    ....

    fun saveNewItem(item: ItemModel) = repository.saveNewItem(item: ItemModel)

}
```

Now call this method from OnClickListener of your save button. That's it.

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener {
    ....

    val newItem = ItemModel(/*add data from editext here*/)

    viewModel.saveNewItem(newItem)

    // You don't have to wait for the result of your insertion operation since you're just adding it into a list. If you were to use the database, then you might need to wait for the insertion and then finish the activity.

    Toast.makeText(this, "New item added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    activity.finish()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Parag! But I ran into the following problems: in `ContentViewModel` in line `fun saveNewItem(item: ItemModel) = repository.saveNewItem(item: ItemModel)` and more specifically in the last `.saveNewItem(item: ItemModel)` - itemModel - Unexpected type specification. And in the logic for the Save button: `viewModel.saveNewItem(newItem)` - viewModel - Unresolved reference and `activity.finish()` - activity - is also Unresolved reference.

Comment: You're just copy-pasting the code, try to understand the logic behind it. These are just syntactical errors, you should be able to solve those on your own. Check the spellings, data-type on those lines. Since you're in the activity itself, remove the reference to `activity` and use only `finish()`.

Comment: You need to call a method from viewModel, then don't you think you'll need an instance of ViewModel, from where you're trying to call this method? You need to initialise the viewmodel In the same file where you've your save button onClicklistener.

Comment: @Anderson How do you know if it's not right? I mean how are you testing it? What is the expected result after you add the item to the items ArrayList in the repository?

Comment: `val newItem = ItemModel(/*add data from editext here*/) viewModel.saveNewItem(newItem)` I could not figure out these lines. Specifically, how and what data needs to be added to `ItemModel()` and with an error in the line `viewModel ...` and therefore my program crashes.

Comment: @Anderson, how come you don't know what to add in `ItemModel`. You've already created a list of `ItemModel` yourself, haven't you? Do you know how class constructor works? How to add data to an object? It's basics. Maybe you should clear out your fundamental before diving into complex code/logic. Have you done any android courses or something before starting this whole project?

Comment: The fact is that when I click on the Save button, the window with the addition of a new item simply closes, but nothing is added at the end of the list of items.

Comment: How are you checking if anything is added to the list or not? And btw you're not storing anything on the database, so whenever you finish the activity the instance of the viewmodel and repository must be getting destroyed, so you won't see that item added there anyway.

Comment: According to your code, we violate some of the SOLID principles, so I think that in my situation I need to create a separate view model for NewItemActivity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234814/discussion-between-parag-pawar-and-anderson).